# len(n) x len(m) array in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

```
n = ' AAADDDEEE'
m = ' AADDDEB'
```

How to create numpy of dimensions len(n) x len(m) where n is the first row, m is first column and all the other entries are empty

i.e.

```
  A A A D D D E E E 
A [][][][][][][][][]
A [][][][][][][][][]
D [][][][][][][][][]
D [][][][][][][][][]
D [][][][][][][][][]
E [][][][][][][][][]
B [][][][][][][][][]
```

I was trying something along the lines of

```
import numpy as np
print np.array(list(n),list(m))
```

but it only takes on argument . . . i'm not sure how to exactly go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> arr = np.empty((len(m), len(n)), dtype=str)
>>> arr.fill('')
>>> arr[0] = list(n)
>>> arr[:,0] = list(m)
>>> arr
array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
       ['A', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['D', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['D', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['D', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['E', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['B', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>>
```

Comment: why does np.empty make random characters ?

Comment: because it doesn't initialize values, only maps memory. use `zeros` instead.

Comment: @O.rka If you don't want random value then use `numpy.full`: `np.full((len(m), len(n)), '', dtype=str)`, this will initialize an array with empty strings.